# How do you get the swap space configured for Docker for Mac via command line?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Docker for Mac has a GUI interface for setting the cpu, ram, and swap values for the Hypervisor which hosts containers. All 3 of these settings are visible by opening up the docker menu and going to Preferences -> Advanced.

In addition the cpu and ram settings can be parsed from the output of `docker info` command, but the swap information is not listed there. Nor could I find any other docker cli utilities that output the swap setting info for Docker for Mac.

How do you obtain this swap setting info via command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Mac stores the settings in an iso file located at: `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/config.iso`.

If Docker for Mac is running this file will be in use and cannot be mounted using `hdiutil` so the following sequence of commands is suggested to get the swap settings:

```
cp ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/config.iso /tmp/config.iso
# Mount the iso image
hdiutil mount /tmp/config.iso  2>&1 > /dev/null 
# Parse the swap information from the config file (json format) using python
cat /Volumes/config/config |  python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['swap']['entries']['size']['content']"
# Unmount the iso image
hdiutil eject /Volumes/config  2>&1 > /dev/null
rm /tmp/config.iso
```

Note: If Docker for Mac is not running then you do not need to copy the iso file from its original location you can simply mount it in place. If you try mounting the config.iso file in its original location while Docker for Mac is running you will get an error as follows:

```
hdiutil: mount failed - Resource temporarily unavailable
```

An example of the output is below:

```
2048M
```